# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when executing Java code

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, when I execute the below code.
Could someone explain me why I am facing this? All I need to do is to connect to the db and fetch some values from it. Is it a problem with the eclipse that I use?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class test_sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
              System.out.println("Test1");
              DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                  System.out.println("Test2");
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ussbazudb126.ussb.winson.net:1521/epdev", "manager", "<<PASSWORD>>");
              System.out.println("Test3");
             // Statement st = con.createStatement();
              PreparedStatement meta = con.prepareStatement("select project from isac_extract");
              System.out.println("Test4");
              ResultSet rset = meta.executeQuery();
              while (rset.next()) {
                  String project = rset.getString(1);
                  System.out.println(project);}
              }
              catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              finally {System.out.println("Final Block");}

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail (at least the full stack trace of the exception) surely we are not magical wizards and we don't know what class is not found. But I bet it says that it can't find the oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver because you didn't include the driver JAR file on the classpath of your little application.

Comment: Could you at least provide the full ClassNotFoundException output?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

Comment: Also that server, is on the internet, so I hope you didn't just specify the "manager" user's password to that database. I am sure it's just a dev database, but you shouldn't probably do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download appropriate Oracle JDBC driver from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). If you are using Eclipse you need to add ojdbc14.jar which contains the OracleDriver class to your build path. It is usually located in:
{ORACLE DRIVER INSTALL PATH}\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

If you are not using an IDE you need to add the path to that JAR to your -classpath option.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project properties (Project -> Properties) -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external JARs -> select jar with Oracle Driver from your filesystem (you can download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) if you haven't already). That should help.

Comment: @Matteo Did you read the question carefully? He clearly stated that he *is* using Eclipse ("Is it a problem with the eclipse that I use?"), so my answer is probably the most specific for him. Why did you downvoted me then?

Comment: +1 Alternativly copy the jar to a subdir in your project and just use `Add Jar`.

Comment: @Fatal Yeah, this is even better solution because it makes your project portable (relative path is used instead of absolute). I wanted my answer to be as straightforward as possible but it's usually better to do what Fatal suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I have loaded the jar.. but now i receive a dii err..

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely  : `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` is missing from your classpath, check it.

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please let me know how can i do tat ??

Comment: It depends on your IDE, however it's enough add this option -classpath libname.jar when you launch the application.

Answer (score 1):

Include Oracle JDBC driver in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle 11g, you need to place 
**ojdbc6.jar** 
in Java Classpath. The **ojdbc.jar** can be found on Oracle home directory E:\app\shyam\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib.
We can simply put **ojdbc6.jar** in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext directory instead of defining Java Classpath also.